# Console log on click event with textbox

Tags: javascript

I know this is probably a duplicate question. I am trying to use the value of a textbox and just show it in my console.log. It appears for a second and disappears.

Here is my HTML form

```
<form>
    <input type ="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." size="45" required>
    <input type ="submit" value="GO" id="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
$(function(){


$("#submit").on("click", function(){

    var t = document.getElementById("search").value;
    console.log(t);


    });
});
```

For future context, I am trying to use that information to plug it into the wikipedia API.

```
        var wikipediaURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ t +"&format=json&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        url: wikipediaURL,
        type:'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status, jqXR){
            console.log(data);
        },
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("fail");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
```

Comment: It disappears because the form is submitted and the current DOM is replaced by the response. The fact that the message disappears doesn't mean that the value isn't gotten correctly though.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense why return false solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Reason you see it for a moment in your console and then it's disappear is you are using submit button inside your form and whenever you click submit button it will by default submit the form and refresh the page if target is same page unless you stop form submission.

In order to avoid form submission try this.

```
$(function(){


$("#submit").on("click", function(){

    var t = document.getElementById("search").value;
    console.log(t);
    e.preventDefault(); // this will also do the trick and avoid form submission.
    return false; // return statement is included just as safety measure as this will make sure form is not submitted. 

    });
});
```